# How to use AND operator in match (Kibana dev tools)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using dev Tools  , Bellow Query works fine in Kibana Discover

```
log.file.path:*MY.log*    AND "[COMMAND:HEARTBEAT]"  AND "[CHARGING:0]"
```

but when i am doing the same in Dev tools, its only taking the HEARTBEAT but its showing all data where Charging 0 and 1, but I just need 0

```
GET filebeat-*/_search
{
  "size": 1000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "log.file.path": "LOG.log"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "COMMAND": {
              "value": "HEARTBEAT"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "CHARGING": {
              "value": "0"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "gte": "now-15m"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

LOG Mapping
Same Log i am geteting 2 way,
one in message and  by using logstash i am trasforming as Json , I added both in here

```
{
  "_index": "filebeat-7.2.0-2019.09.14",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "Aps9MW0BBmrGS9dAswgZ",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "ecs": {
      "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "@version": "1",
    "message": "[COMMAND:HEARTBEAT],[GPS STATUS:true],[INFO:false],[SIGNAL:false],[ENGINE:0],[DOOR:0],[LON:0],[LAT:0],[SPEED:0.0],[HEADING:-1.0],[BATTERY:100.0%],[CHARGING:0],[O&E:CONNECTED],",


    "GPS-LOG": {
      "O&E": "CONNECTED",
      "GPS POS": "true",
      "ENGINE": "0",
      "COMMAND": "HEARTBEAT",
      "GSM_SIGNAL": "75",

      "CHARGING": "0",
      "HEADING": "-1.0",
      "FUEL": "0.0V/0.0%",
      "SPEED": "0.0",
      "GPS STATUS": "true",
      "ALARM": "NONE",
      "BATTERY": "100.0%",
      "TIMESTAMP": "null",
      "LON": "0",
      "LAT": "0",
      "DOOR": "0",
      "SERIAL": "1670",
      "SIGNAL": "false",
      "INFO": "false",
      "GPS_SATS": "11"
    },
```

My Real Logs are this

```
    18:15:53,909 DEBUG [com.] (default-threads - 57) (338)>[TIMESTAMP:Sun Sep 15 18:15:53 UTC 2019],[COMMAND:INFO],[GPS STATUS:true],[INFO:true],[SIGNAL:false],[ENGINE:0],[DOOR:0],[LON:90],[LAT:2],[SPEED:0.0],[HEADING:240.0],[BATTERY:83.0%],[CHARGING:0],[O&E:CONNECTED],[GSM_SIGNAL:100],[GPS_SATS:8],[GPS POS:true],[FUEL:0.0V/0.0%],[ALARM:NONE],[SERIAL:03AA]
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kibana Discovery uses a Lucene Syntax (Lucene is the search engine/technology Elasticsearch is built on) to let you query your data. However when you send requests via the DevTool you basically call the **Elasticsearch REST API**. You can **not** use the Lucene syntax there.

Your second match query is the problem:

I assume you want to search for exact matches (command == HEARTBEAT; charging == 0). But with the match query you are doing a **fulltext search** on the fields.

Instead of the match query you need to use the [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html). So after the first match query you would define two term queries (one for the command field and one for the charging field) inside the must-clause. Notice that when using the **must** clause it automatically applies an AND-operator on all queries inside it.

This is how your query could look like (untested):

```
GET filebeat-*/_search
{
  "size": 1000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "log.file.path": "MYlog"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "command": {
              "value": "HEARTBEAT"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "charging": {
              "value": 0
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "gte": "now-15m"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can search on the command.**keyword** field.

Comment: Hi, I tryed that but not giving any thing, my logs are like this 
``` [COMMAND:HEARTBEAT],[GPS STATUS:true],[INFO:false],[SIGNAL:false],[ENGINE:0],[DOOR:0],[LON:0],[LAT:0],[SPEED:0.0],[HEADING:-1.0],[BATTERY:100.0%],[CHARGING:0] ``` , Since I am using logstash, I also get logs as JSON so either way i am happy to get

Comment: Then please share your mappings of the relevant data.

Comment: I have edited the Questino section with log mapping,  my logs comming as message and also byusing logstash i am transforming as JSON, i added both

Comment: What You meant by mapping ? sorry i am quite knew to ES , i just added my real logs in Questino section, is that you meant mapping ?

Comment: also Edited the question with Real log and the search which you advised in your solutions section